# How does "bwareaopen" work?

Tags: matlab, pixel

I saw the documentation of `bwareaopen`, but what was confusing me is the number of pixels. When we say `8-neighbourhood`, doesn't that mean `9-pixels`? In this function, we specify the number of pixels, and if you see the example provided in the documentation, you will find that they mention `50-pixels`, does that simply mean a `10x5` window?

So, if we specify the number of pixels, what will the function exactly do? It mentions removing small pixels. What does this exactly mean? Isn't each square in an image matrix considered a square? What is a `small` pixel in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Please, accept the answer if solves your question or comment the doubts if it doesnt!

Answer (score 5):

You are mixing 2 of the variables. 
in the documentation we can see the following:

```
BW2 = bwareaopen(BW, P)
BW2 = bwareaopen(BW, P, conn)
```

Where you have `P` and `conn` variables.

`conn` is the neighbourhood variable. With this you chose with values you understand as "neigbour". See example:

```
conn=4;

- X -
X 0 X
- X - 

conn=8

X X X
X 0 X
X X X
```

Higher numbers are for higher dimensions.
but the `P` variable is the variable to choose what is "small". **The function `bwareaopen` will delete white areas smaller than `P` pixels.**

In the example in the documentation you can see:

```
    BW = imread('text.png');
    BW2 = bwareaopen(BW, 50);
    imshow(BW);
```

But that "50" is the `P` variable, not `conn`. as `conn` is not defined it will be set as default, in this case 8.